# print strings from inside linux ntworking driver

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I have written a linux networking driver.

This is my "hard_header" function:

```
 int snull_header(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev,
               unsigned short type, void *daddr, void *saddr,
             unsigned int len)
 {
   struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)skb_push(skb,ETH_HLEN);

   pr_err("inside snull_header\n");
   pr_err("THE DATA TO SEND BEFORE ADDITION IS:%s\n", skb->data);
   pr_err("THE SOURCE IS:%s\n", (char*)saddr);
   pr_err("THE DEST IS:%s\n", (char*)daddr);
   eth->h_proto = htons(type);
   memcpy(eth->h_source, saddr ? saddr : dev->dev_addr, dev->addr_len);
   memcpy(eth->h_dest,   daddr ? daddr : dev->dev_addr, dev->addr_len);
   eth->h_dest[ETH_ALEN-1]   ^= 0x01;   /* dest is us xor 1 */
   pr_err("THE DATA TO SEND AFTER ADDITION IS:%s\n", skb->data);
   return (dev->hard_header_len);
 }
```

This is the definition of pr_err (from printk.h):

```
    #define pr_err(fmt, ...) \
    printk(KERN_ERR pr_fmt(fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

When I run load this driver and try to send packet, I see all the prints, but instead of the strings of skb->data, source and destination I see gibberish.
My guess is that it's related somehow to the fact I'm referring to kernel memory, but on the other hand, this is what printk is for.

How can I print correctly these strings?

Comment: Are the strings `\0`-terminated? Where are they made?

Comment: Instead of using pr_err try using '**printk(KERN_INFO "your string here");**'

Answer (score 1):

For the `saddr` and `daddr`, you can not print them in this way. You can print them with:

```
pr_err("THE SOURCE IS:%d.%d.%d.%d\n",
       (0xff & saddr),
       (0xff00 & saddr) >> 8,
       (0xff000000 & saddr) >> 16
       (0xff000000 & saddr) >>24);
```

For the `skb->data`, it's not null(`'\0'`) terminated so you can not printed as string with the format `"%s"`. the limit of the `skb->data` determined by `skb->len`. You can print the content of the `skb->data` in this way.

```
int i; 
for (i=0; i<skb->len; i++) 
    printk("%c", skb->data+i );
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick answer. I tried to print skb->data in the exact way you suggeted. But all I get is 42 '<-' characters, like all the ip packet consists only of arrow characters. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of skb->data vary depending on which networking layer you are printing it. It can contain the header of previous layers even. So get the length of the data. And then print the data bytewise for the length. Then analyse what it contains. skb->data_len gives the size of data.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your quick answer. I tried to print the data this way:

Comment: char str[256];
 struct ethhdr *eth;
 pr_err("inside snull_header\n");
 if (skb->len < 256)
 {
  strncpy(str,skb->data, skb->len);
  str[skb->data_len] = '\0';
 }
 pr_err("THE DATA LENGTH BEFORE FIRST ADDITION IS:%d\n", skb->len);
 pr_err("THE DATA TO SEND BEFORE ADDITION IS:%s\n", str);

Comment: When I did it, I got that the data len is 42, but in the data it printed nothing, like the data is an empty string.

Comment: Can you explain, what do you mean by " print the data bytewise for the length"?